# iOS: dragGesture don't move element

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app I have this code to drag an object

I set my gesture:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *downwardGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer new] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChanged:)];
downwardGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
[grid_element addGestureRecognizer:downwardGesture];
for (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers)
{
    [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:downwardGesture];
}
```

and in my method:

```
- (void) dragGestureChanged:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture{

    UIImageView *imageToMove;
    CGPoint pointInSelfView;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        dragging = TRUE;
        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:grid_element];
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [grid_element indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
        if (selectedIndexPath==nil) {
            dragging = FALSE;
            return;
        }

        indexToHide = selectedIndexPath.row;
        imageToMove = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_1.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageToMove];
        pointInSelfView = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        [imageToMove setCenter:pointInSelfView];


    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        pointInSelfView = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        [imageToMove setCenter:pointInSelfView];

    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded     ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
             gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        dragging = FALSE;
    }
}
```

it work in `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, then `imageToMove` is added in `self.view` in the correct position but `imageToMove` don't drag in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`; I show a `NSLog` for `pointInSelfView` in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and it changes correctly; where is the problem?

**EDIT**

if I use imageToMove as IBOutlet it work fine, but I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARC, the iOS system is releasing object-`imageToMove`.
Creating a property with retain attribute, makes system retains the object and hence it moves.

The only thing I am confused is why there is no error in `[imageToMove setCenter:pointInSelfView];`. There should be an error saying - **message is sent to deallocated instance.** But I am pretty sure that the problem is due to memory release of imageToMove.